# Neo4j: server won't start

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to switch from Java embbeded Neo4j database to standalone server but cannot find a way to import my database.

Whatever I do, I am getting the error: `Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@2190bb62' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.'

The problem is that the log file doesn't show anything useful:

```
2017-04-12 12:25:34.919+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.CommunityNeoServer] ======== Neo4j .1.3 ========
2017-04-12 12:25:35.071+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.d.LifecycleManagingDatabase] Starting...
2017-04-12 12:25:35.608+0000 INFO  [o.n.b.v.r.WorkerFactory] Bolt enabled on localhost:7687.
2017-04-12 12:25:35.722+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.s.p.StoreMigrator] Starting upgrade of database
```

I have activated the `dbms.directories.import=import` option to import an existing database that was created in 2.x

What should I do? is there any way to have more verbose logs?

I tried using Neo4j version 2.x, but I still get the same error when trying to start the server.